# Error while trying to run newman command to generate htmlextra

Tags: postman, newman

```bash
newman run https://api.postman.com/collections/17122467-bf8b5cc9-d6c7-4791-839c-1ac762241273?access_key=PMAT-01HH4V9P0WYHYS8XF9H6W1QC6M -r html
```

when I run above command I get the following error:-

```bash
error: collection could not be loaded
  unable to fetch data from url "https://api.postman.com/collections/17122467-bf8b5cc9-d6c7-4791-839c-1ac762241273?access_key=PMAT-01HH4V9P0WYHYS8XF9H6W1QC6M"
  tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND cloud-cluster122197-swg.ibosscloud.com
```

I am trying to generate htmextra report using newman but facing below issue:

```bash
error: collection could not be loaded
  unable to fetch data from url "https://api.postman.com/collections/17122467-bf8b5cc9-d6c7-4791-839c-1ac762241273?access_key=PMAT-01HH4V9P0WYHYS8XF9H6W1QC6M"
  tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND cloud-cluster122197-swg.ibosscloud.com
```